# Eclipse - multiline comment with asterisks doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm not able to use ani shortcuts for using comments with asterisk. Every key combination doesn't work. I tried with `CTRL`+`/`, `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`/`, `CTRL`+`C`; all of these have the same output, i.e. a simple comment with `//` on every line. Other shortcuts like `CTRL`+`\`, `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`\` or `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F` doesn't work at all.

So, how can I have this shortcut?
These are the `Comments` options

[image: Comments option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Window>Preferences>General>Keys>type "add block comment" in the search box, you should see:

[image]

the type "remove block comment"

[image]

These settings are by default, but if the shortcut is not working on your machine, you must be missing these bindings, To create them, you need to mark the command "Add Block Comment", then click inside the "Binding" field and press CTRL+SHIFT+/, then press Apply. The same is for uncommenting.

Comment: well, as @bdulac pointed out, it seems that the problem is with the italian keyboard: it doesn't have the `/` key (it is available only via `Shift`+`7`). So, I have to change the default combinations for many elements. Problem is that not all the combinations work, because I think that some of there are already in use. Is there any way to show an info box when I am going to overwrite another key combination?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem to the one you have: the / shortcut seems to trigger a folding operation (at least in the Java editor) that does not appear in the keys preferences table.

Modifying the key in the keys preferences table seems to work fine: setting the binding to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for the "Add Block Comment" command sets the expected block comment.

The reason is clear to me: the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> binding is very difficult to reproduce in a Linux environment because Eclipse makes a clear difference Numpad_Divide and the '/'. The Normal '/' strike is being modified by the shift key (French keyboard).